# SAP Commerce: Implementation of AutoPick function in 2005

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

I am currently implementing configurableBundle extension and testing the auto pick functionality. Is see that there is an "isAutoPick" function in configurableBundle addon. But I do not see any usages. In this article (https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/2005/en-US/8b887b9d866910148ac4c2ee46e16461.html?q=auto%20pick%20subscription), it states that the addToCart functionality is implemented in the subscriptionservice addon. But looking through the source code, I do not see the implementation for it. How does the auto pick functionality is implemented by default? If there is no default implementation, how would you set it up?

I tried to ask this question in community.sap.com but so far no answer. So I hope the StackoverFlow community is quicker and better with the response.

Best regards

Andy